# Bubble sort em lista

Tags: c

Eu estou tentando ordenar uma simples lista encadeada, mas não estou conseguindo, só altera o primeiro nó porque o valor é menor, o resto não altera.

```
void ordenar(lista **l) {

    int tam = tamanho((*l));
    lista *prev, *current = (*l)->prox;

    for(int i=0; i<tam - 1; i++) {
        prev = *l;
        for(int j=0; j<tam; j++) {
            if(prev->data > current->data) {
                troca(prev, current);
            }
            current = prev->prox;
        }
        prev = prev->prox;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `current = (*l)->prox` deve estar dentro do primeiro laço para recomeçar toda vez.

O `prev = prev->prox` deve estar dentro do segundo laço para percorrer a lista.

E o `current = prev->prox` deve ser trocado por `current = current->prox` para continuar a percorrer a lista.

Como o `current` já começa com o segundo elemento, o segundo laço `for` deve ir até `tam-1` para não acessar um elemento inexistente.

```
void ordenar(lista **l) {

    int tam = tamanho((*l));
    lista *prev, *current;

    for(int i=0; i<tam - 1; i++) {
        prev = *l;
        current = (*l)->prox;
        for(int j=0; j<tam -1; j++) {
            if(prev->data > current->data) {
                troca(prev, current);
            }
            current = current->prox;
            prev = prev->prox;
        }
    }
}
```

Eu acredito que assim deve estar funcionando, teste no seu código e veja se está OK ou se ainda há algo errado.

Comment: por que o segundo for vai até < pos - 1, e último elemento?

Comment: Porque prev começa no primeiro elemento e o current no segundo. Se não colocar o pos-1, no final do for o prev irá até último elemento e o current acessará um elemento que não existe e causará erro.

Comment: Com o pos-1 o prev irá até o penúltimo e o current até o último, fazendo as trocas normalmente.

Comment: ah, agora entendi. fiz uma versão sem o uso do for. Ficou mais legível.  https://pastebin.com/1qXNb8ps